# I can't cast my object after sending it with netty

Tags: java, networking, netty

When I read the response in the server, I get the right object but when I try to cast it to Packet, I got this exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to server.Packet
    at server.JCoincheServerHandler.channelRead(JCoincheServerHandler.java:21)
```

This is my packet class :

```
public class Packet implements Serializable
{
    public int code;
    int intData;
    String data;
    String user;
}
```

This is how I send it in my client:
The sending is successful, "send failed" is never printed

```
    public void sendMessage(Object object)
    {
        ChannelFuture cf = _chan.write(object);
        _chan.flush();
        if (!cf.isSuccess()) {
            System.out.println("Send failed: " + cf.cause());
        }
}
```

This is how I read it in my server:

```
@Override
   public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
       Packet packet = (Packet) msg;
       System.out.println(packet.data);
       System.out.println("Message received");
   }
```

What did I do wrong ?

EDIT:

```
p.addLast(
          new ObjectEncoder(),
          new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)),
          handler);
```

Comment: What do your pipelines look like?  Need to know which handlers are being added and in which order

Comment: @ChrisO'Toole I edited my post

Comment: Is it possible that you are sending a String instead of Packet?

Comment: @ChrisO'Toole No I send a packet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client must be sending a String.

Also verify that your client and server shares the class Packet and this class should be in the same packet.

For example common.Packet